# Calculating $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x+x^2}} dx$

Tags: calculus

I am struggling in evaluating the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x+x^2}} dx$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a relatively simple way to compute it. Convert your integral, by completing the square, to

$$I = 2 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{(2x+1)^2 -1}} dx$$

Let $2x+1 = \cosh \theta$. Using $\cosh^2 \theta -1 = \sinh^2 \theta$, we get

$$I = \int_{0}^{\cosh^{-1} 3} (\frac{\cosh \theta -1}{2})^3 d \theta$$

Is this enough of a hint to let you continue?

I am averse to nasty computation which I think lies ahead here, but if someone wants to see it, or has a nice way to avoid it, let me know.